# Open and close fragment from the same button?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the activity that have fragment. Now I have button that open the fragment. I am wondering how I can use the same button for openning and closing fragment?
My code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragmentTransaction fTrans;
    Button reg;
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);
            frag1 = new Fragment1();
        }
        public void openFragment(View v){
            fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fTrans.add(R.id.frgmCont, frag1);
            fTrans.commit();
        }
    }
```

XML file of MainActivity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication5.MainActivity">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/reg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Registration"
    android:background="@drawable/add_btn"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:onClick="openFragment"
    />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frgmCont"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the fragment:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);

    }
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your activity code to this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FragmentTransaction fTrans;
Button reg;
boolean flag = false;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);
        frag1 = new Fragment1();
    }
    public void openFragment(View v){
        fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if(flag) {
            fTrans.remove(frag1);
        } else {
            fTrans.add(R.id.frgmCont, frag1);
        }
        flag = !flag;
        fTrans.commit();
    }
}
```